# how print out the actual previous Node in DoublyLinkedList?

Tags: python, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I have LinkedList data structure and I have updated to doubly-linked -list with adding 'prev' key to return or add the previous Node but the problem isn't showing the result actual previous node

This is my code for LinkedList and I have updated to doubly LinkedList by adding 'prev' key for each method

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.head = {
            'value':value,
            'next':None,
            'prev':None,
        }
        self.tail = self.head
        self.length  = 1

    def append(self, value):
        self.newnode = {
            'value':value,
            'next':None,
            'prev':None,
        }
        self.newnode['prev'] = self.tail
        self.tail['next'] = self.newnode 
        self.tail = self.newnode 
        self.length +=1
        return self.head 

a = LinkedList(10)
a.append(11)
print(a.append(3))
```

The output is 
`{'value': 10, 'next': {'value': 11, 'next': {'value': 3, 'next': None, 'prev': {...}}, 'prev': {...}}, 'prev': None}`

why print out in 'prev' this {...}} and I want to print out the actual Node dictionary

Comment: Because the node at that location has already been printed in this statement. If it followed every link back and forth, it would be an infinite loop.

Comment: the problem is ```self.newnode['prev'] = self.tail``` but what you think to solve that

Comment: To solve it you need to write a loop that prints out each node and stops when `self.next` equals `self.head`. You could put such a loop in a new, separate method of the class.

Comment: May be useing  assignment without looping because I want to be BigO(1) not BigO(n) @martineau

Comment: Your data structure is recursive, which Python's print statement notices and begin printing `...` when it encounters the same node again. Regardless, printing the contents of the list is a BigO(n) operation—no way around that.

Comment: but the problem is  origin code with JavaScript used assignment doesn't use any looping for that I wired why doesn't work such as Python @martineau